# What is Centre of Polynomial ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Recently this question come to me, what it the centre of a polynomial ring $R[x]$ where $R$ is a ring ( we do not know if its commutative or even until) . intuitionally I can see $Z(R[x])=Z(R)[x]$. so is I am right?

My attempt:-
Since $p(x)q(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i x^i \sum_{j=0}^{m} b_j x^j= \sum_{i=0}^{n+m}c_i x^i$. where $c_i$ is a product of some coefficient of in $p(x),q(x)$. so if those coefficient commute ( that is they are in $Z(R)$ since we take them arbitrary) later we can recover $q(x)$ and $p(x)$ after we commute the cofficent.

Comment: What have you done to try to prove this? Can you show containment in one direction?

Comment: Since $p(x)q(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i x^i \sum_{j=0}^{m} b_j x^j= \sum_{i=1}^{n+m}c_i x^i$. where $c_i$ is a product of some coefficient of in $p(x),q(x)$. so if those coefficient commute ( or in $Z(R)$ so we will get $p(x),q(x)$ also in $Z(R[x])$. I know its messy but I need to work on it.

Comment: you should add this to your question. It will help us help you in many different ways. 1. We will have a better idea of what level you are at so we can tailor our answers to that and 2. Most people are more motivated to help someone that we know actually gave an attempt rather than someone that is just waiting to be handed the answer.

Comment: thanks.. I will put it there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct in your intuition.

As you noticed: if $f\left(x\right)=a_{0}+\cdots+a_{n}x^{n}\in Z\left(R\right)\left[x\right]$
and $g\left(x\right)=b_{0}+\cdots+b_{m}x^{m}\in Z\left(R\right)\left[x\right]$
then it is straightforward to verify $f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)=g\left(x\right)f\left(x\right)$.

If conversely $h\left(x\right)=c_{0}+\cdots+c_{k}x^{k}\in Z\left(R\left[x\right]\right)$
then for each $r\in R$ we have: $$rc_{0}+\cdots+rc_{k}x^{k}=rh\left(x\right)=h\left(x\right)r=c_{0}r+\cdots+c_{k}rx^{k}$$

The multiplications after first and second $=$ sign takes place in the polynomial ring where $r$ stands for a constant polynomial.

This justifies the conclusion that $c_{i}\in Z\left(R\right)$ for each $i$.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently that $Z(R)[x]\subset Z(R[x])$. Let us show the reverse inclusion.
Assume the contraty. 
Let $A(x) = \sum\limits_{j\geq 0}a_jx^j\in Z(R[x])\setminus Z(R)[x]$. Then there exists $j_0\geq 0$ and $b\in R\subset R[x]$ such that $a_{j_0}b\neq ba_{j_0}$. 
So, we obtain
$$
A(x)b \neq bA(x).
$$
This is contradiction with $A(x)\in Z(R[x])$.